# Extracting row from matrix in Python and use that row as a color in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

This should be easy, but I haven't gotten the hang of Python syntax yet. I create an array like this:

```
colors = [ [(17.0/256.0), (15.0/256.0), (48.0/256.0)],  #Dark blue  (#110F30)
         [(239.0/256.0), (83.0/256.0), (25.0/256.0)]    #Orange     (#EF5319)
         ]
```

I the want to use the first or second row as a color input in the plot statement:

```
ax1.plot(time, temp - 273, color=colors[0,:], label=temp_axis_label)
```

However, this does not work (obviously). What is the correct syntax to extract the rows from the color matrix?

Comment: do you need a list or a single value for `color`?

Comment: I need a list, as in (r,b,g). It works if the colors matrix is a list like `colors = [(17.0/256.0), (15.0/256.0), (48.0/256.0)]`, but I want to create a whole matrix that contains all colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply : `ax1.plot(time, temp - 273, color=colors[0], label=temp_axis_label)`

The problem lies in the fact that colors is a list of list, not a numpy matrix 
:

```
colors = np.array([ [(17.0/256.0), (15.0/256.0), (48.0/256.0)],  #Dark blue  (#110F30)
         [(239.0/256.0), (83.0/256.0), (25.0/256.0)]    #Orange     (#EF5319)
         ])
ax1.plot(time, temp - 273, color=colors[0,:], label=temp_axis_label)
```

works too.

Comment: What? Python is way too easy for me :-P Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

drop the `,:`...

```
color = colors[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
ax1.plot(time, temp - 273, color=colors[0], label=temp_axis_label)
```

you might also consider using numpy: [Link](https://numpy.org/) if you are familiar with matlab and want to perform scientific computation with Python